# Flutter video player wont accept self signed https connection

Tags: flutter, dart, ssl-certificate, html5-video, self-signed

I'm working on a Flutter app that is connecting to assets in the cloud that are using self signed HTTPS.

In the Flutter app I am using Chewie and VideoPlayerController from the lib below:

```
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
```

The video playback crashes when it encounters the HTTPS asset using self signed SSL certificate. I don't see any options to ignore this "issue".

The error is somewhat generic but when I switch back to HTTP it works just fine. This is the error I get from the player when using the self signed HTTPS link.

```
PlatformException: Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
```

There should be some way to use a self signed SSL but how can I go about doing that?

Comment: Same issue. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Hi dan The VideoPlayer widget should support self signed SSL. There's plenty of use cases for not having a CA signed certificate.

I also have the same issue, resolved it by getting the proper CA Certificate and doing some Network security configuration in android folder, please check below link for Network security configuration https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CustomTrust

Answer (score 1):

Enable CleartextTraffic in Android manifest

```
// android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

<application
        android:label="App Name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
```